# Can cryptographically strong UUIDs be generated in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, guid, uuid

What is the state of today's web browsers (Chrome, IE, Safari & Firefox) and their ability to create cryptographically strong UUIDs? In researching this question I have been unable to find anything definitive.  I have come across info on stackoverflow and elsewhere that points to issues with Math.random but I would like to know what the current state of all this is.

**UPDATE**

As **icktoofay** pointed out, `crypto.getRandomValues` is the way to do this.  Unfortunately, support across browsers is limited.  Is there a proven way to work around this?  Are there any javascript libraries that tackle this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'cryptographically strong UUID'? UUIDs aren't supposed to be cryptographically anything - they're meant to be unique.

Comment: I am referring to the quality of the random number generator.  Does it have enough entropy, is it crypto grade.

Comment: In the context of UUIDs there's no requirement for randomness, just uniqueness. The two are not synonymous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In browsers that have it, you can use [`crypto.getRandomValues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.crypto.getRandomValues) to get cryptographically-secure pseudorandom values. For example:

```
var array = new Uint8Array(16);
crypto.getRandomValues(array);
```

You can then manipulate those bytes into a valid UUID.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  With support for crypto.getRandomValues limited are there other ways to get stronger randomness?  I will update the question.

Comment: @user1843640: `crypto.getRandomValues` is the best option you've got, but if that's not available, you might want to look at [how SJCL does it](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/random.js).

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't directly answer the original question, it might help someone looking for a library to help with UUID creation.  For my current needs I have decided to use the [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) library.  From the feature list:

- Generate RFC4122 version 1 or version 4 UUIDs
- **Cryptographically strong random # generation on supporting platforms**

Looking at the source it seems to accomplish this by using crypto.getRandomValues which is what @icktoofay suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, No!
Long answer, http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Trust me, I researched into this issue for a while. Crypto is experimental, and thus for the majority of browsers, it is a no. Node might however be better since it ties directly into the OS. You will need to research that though!